# Atualização do botão notificação

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dinâmico

Tenho um botão notificação no meu software, onde eu queria que ele automaticamente se atualiza-se sozinho. Então fiz o seguinte código:

```html
setTimeout(mostrarNotificacao, 90000);
  
function mostrarNotificacao(){
  //function mostrarModal(idPedidos){
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var url = "../../componentes/php/ff_notificacao_php.php";
        $('.modal-content').load(url,
        function(resultado){
         $('#conteudoNotificacao').html(resultado);
        });
    });
  }
```

Porém enquanto não da 1,5 minutos o botão não aparece, após isso aparece, tem algum jeito melhor de se fazer isso?

Comment: voce quer que apareça de inicio, e depois nos intervalos?

Comment: Isso mesmo lucas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que queira que a função mostrarNotificacao() seja chamada a cada 1,5 minuto. Se for assim existem duas formas: 1) usar a função setInterval() em vez de setTimeout() no exemplo que o @lucas-torres deu; 2) chamar novamente o setTimeout() dentro da função mostrarNotificacao(), logo depois de executar o código principal.

Mas em ambos casos, acho que seja mais adequado definir a função mostrarNotificacao() dentro da $(document).ready().

Ou seja, pelo modo 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     mostrarNotificacao();
     setInterval(mostrarNotificacao, 90000);

     function mostrarNotificacao() {
        var url = "../../componentes/php/ff_notificacao_php.php";
        $('.modal-content').load(url, function(resultado) {
            $('#conteudoNotificacao').html(resultado);
        });
    }
  });
```

e pelo modo 2):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var timerId = 0;
     mostrarNotificacao();

     function mostrarNotificacao() {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        var url = "../../componentes/php/ff_notificacao_php.php";
        $('.modal-content').load(url, function(resultado) {
            $('#conteudoNotificacao').html(resultado);
            timerId = setTimeout(mostrarNotificacao, 90000);
        });
    }
  });
```

A vantagem desse segundo modo é que, caso a resposta do load() demore mais que 1,5 minuto, um timeout não vai se sobrepor ao outro.

Comment: Eldes, muito obrigado, usei o método 2. Agradeço a sua ajuda e por ter gastado seu tempo.

Answer (score 0):

Basta acrescentar uma chamada antes, e depois conte o tempo:

```
mostrarNotificacao()
setInterval(mostrarNotificacao, 90000);

function mostrarNotificacao(){
  //function mostrarModal(idPedidos){
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var url = "../../componentes/php/ff_notificacao_php.php";
        $('.modal-content').load(url,
        function(resultado){
         $('#conteudoNotificacao').html(resultado);
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Lucas, desse modo a função mostrarNotificacao() vai ser chamada apenas 2 vezes: a primeira vez quando é chamada diretamente na primeira lina do código, e depois mais uma única vez depois de 1,5 minuto pela setTimeout(). Se entendi bem o Gabriel precisa que seja chamada sem parar, a cada 1,5 minuto.

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: @LucasTorres obrigado, mas como o eldes lhe disse, preciso que a cada 1,5 minuto seja feita uma verificação no php. Mas agradeço.